# RejectedExecutionException thrown with code copied from API

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm using a ScheduledExecutorService to try to run a method every two hours. New to this, I've simply copied the code from the API docs, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html and changed a couple of names. But I always get a

```
Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@2e22a rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@89f481b[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2078)
```

I can't see what's terminating the scheduler.

Here's my code:

```
public class IrrigationScheduler {
    private static final String TAG = IrrigationScheduler.class.getSimpleName();

    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);

    private Irrigator irrigator;

    public IrrigationScheduler(Irrigator irrigator){
        this.irrigator = irrigator;
    }

    public void waterEvery2Hours() {
        final Runnable waterer = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // irrigator.irrigateAll();
                Log.d(TAG, "irrigating");
            }
        };
        final ScheduledFuture<?> wateringScheduleHandler = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(waterer, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);//TimeUnit.HOURS
        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                wateringScheduleHandler.cancel(true);
            }
        }, 60 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void switchOff(){
        scheduler.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could I see the code calling `IrrigationScheduler`? Is there anything calling `switchOff` prematurely?

Comment: I thought of that after posting the above. Commenting out the switchOff code made no difference.

Comment: What is sure is the scheduled thread pool is terminated as shown by the `RejectedExecutionException`: `...[Terminated,...`. You need to find where your tp is shutdown. Easier to help with more contextual code.

Answer (score 0):

The threading code was fine. Alexandre, you were right - I needed to look further back down the line to see what was switching off the thread. The auto irrigation is switched on at the moment by a button in a web page, and somehow that button is being toggled on and off per single request. I'm using NanoHttpd on a Rasp pi, and I think this behaviour is described as 'bounce' Anyway, that's where I need to find my solution - thanks for the suggestions.